# Solving a cubic equation over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I came accross this cube root value that I was hoping to simplify.

\begin{equation}
\sqrt[\leftroot{-0.5}\uproot{10}\scriptstyle 3]{8+3\sqrt{21}}
\end{equation}

It motivated the question as to when there exists rational solutions to the following equation.
\begin{equation}
(x+y)^3 = 8 + 3\sqrt{21}\;\;\;\;x,y\in \mathbb{Q}
\end{equation}
Or in more general terms. If given some $a\in \mathbb{R}$ when can I find $x,y \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that
\begin{equation}
(x+y)^3 = a 
\end{equation}
Unfortunately, I have no experience in number theory so I apologise if this is trivial. Can anyone provide an explanation as to how I would go about solving such a problem.

Comment: Formatting note:  it's better to use, e.g., \sqrt[3] x to render $\sqrt[3] x$.

Comment: If $x,y\in\Bbb Q$, then $a=(x+y)^3\in\Bbb Q$ as well, hence $a=u^3/v^3$ for some $u,v\in\Bbb Z$ ($v\neq 0$).

Comment: Maybe you are looking for solutions like $x + y\sqrt{21}$ ?

Comment: Since $(x + y)^3 \in \mathbb Q$, you cannot expect that it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

$$(a + b\sqrt{21})^3 = (a^3 + 63ab^2) + (3a^2b + 21b^3)\sqrt{21}$$
This should equal $8 + 3\sqrt{21}$. Comparing coefficients,
$$a(a^2 + 63b^2) = 8$$
$$b(a^2 + 7b^2) = 1$$

I don't know a better way to do this, but as you can see in the coefficients, if we take $a = b$, then we get $$64a^3 = 8 \qquad \text{and} \qquad8a^3=1$$
Hence $a = b = \frac{1}{2}$, so the answer is $\frac{1}{2}(1 + \sqrt{21})$.

Comment: one sanity check is that the norm of $8 + 3 \sqrt{21}$ is $8^2 - 21 \cdot 3^2 = -125$ which is a rational, and integral, cube.  Thus we need rational $a,b$  with $a^2 - 21 b^2 = -5,$   may or may not allow integers, but of course your halves work. The first integer point would be $a=4,b=1$